# Looking for a Good Mind Mapping Tool

Tags: mind-mapping

I've been looking at mind mapping tools and haven't been able to find exactly what I want, so thought I'd ask the opinion of those more experienced in this area.

Broadly, I'm after a tool for personal use, so collaboration features are a non issue for me.  I'd prefer a tool that available in both the Microsoft and Android environments,though just one of these would be acceptable.  As far as integrations as detailed below are concerned, these can be either inbuilt or via IFTTT, Zapier or similar.  I'm happy to pay a decent amount for the right tool but don't want to be paying Corpoate rates.  Given that broad frame of reference, my specific requirements are:

Must have:

- "Drill Down" ie. Any node in a map can be drilled into so as to form the root node of a "sub-map";
- The ability to attach commentary to a node;
- The ability to link files, documents, spreadsheets, web links etc to a node along with annotation on what the link point to, preferably embedded within the commentary;
- At least minimal support for scheduling (ie. Due by date) but preferably support for marking up task dependancies;
- Integration to both Project Management (preferably Trello) and tasking (preferably Todoist) apps.  Ideally this would be two way (eg. Mark up a task/record task as complete);

Nice to have, but not a deal breaker:

- Support for working offline;
- Flowcharting of execution;

Comment: Are you especially searching for a mobile app? Otherwise freemind seems to be doing quite many of your requirements, on windows.  (I don't know if it can be integrated into task managers. )

Comment: A mind mapping tool with due dates and task dependencies that integrates into Trello? It looks to me like you don't really want a mind mapping tool, but a task manager that is good at creating task hierarchies.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend MindMapper (mindmapper.com):

"I'd prefer a tool that available in both the Microsoft and Android environments,though just one of these would be acceptable." - **Microsoft only**

"Drill Down" ie. Any node in a map can be drilled into so as to form the root node of a "sub-map"; - **yes**

The ability to attach commentary to a node; - **yes**

The ability to link files, documents, spreadsheets, web links etc to a node along with annotation on what the link point to, preferably embedded within the commentary; - **yes**

At least minimal support for scheduling (ie. Due by date) but preferably support for marking up task dependancies; - **yes**

Integration to both Project Management (preferably Trello) and tasking (preferably Todoist) apps. Ideally this would be two way (eg. Mark up a task/record task as complete); - **no, as far as I know**

Answer (score 2):

It could be that [MindMeister](//www.mindmeister.com/mind-map-features/) and/or [MeisterTask](//www.meistertask.com) could be a winning combination for your requirements.

MindMeister at least supports both Windows and Android, has the drill down feature, with possibilities for attached all kinds of stuff to the nodes, and support for tasks and due dates.

Regarding the integration part is where it gets tricky. It does not integrate into Trello or Todoist, but it does integrate into MeisterTask which looks like it is aiming to be a Trello replacement (see [What are the best cloud-based mindmapping tools with integration to Trello?](//www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-cloud-based-mindmapping-tools-with-integration-to-Trello)). However currently this seems to be a one way integration. And I can't find any links to neither ifttt nor zapier, but then again you don't specify why/what kind of integration you need from these two tools?

Regarding pricing, the gratis options are existent, but somewhat limited, so you would need to consider [MindMeister pricing](//www.meistertask.com/pricing) and [MeisterTask pricing](//www.meistertask.com/pricing/) options. The cheapest is 36 EUR/6months for MindMeister, and 7,50 USD/month for MeisterTask. You do however have 30 days trial on MindMeister (and a limited free option).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to first use mindmapping to sketch out a new area of work and then use another program to to the planning for that.

One possibility would be to use [Freemind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeMind). It is free and the advantage for you is that it fulfills many of your requirements but more importantly it can be imported into Abstractspoon [todolist](http://www.abstractspoon.com/tdl_resources.html) (A great little to do list program, and free!).  This is where you get some excellent functionality for task management.  So, due dates, resources, file links, task dependencies, basic Gantt charts etc.

Programs also exist to read the Abstractspoon todolist xml files under Android(tdl todo list) so you can take it mobile and the files are even shareable with others on the same network should you need some team work.

Comment: I have edited your answer for layout. Please [edit] and improve it further: What do you mean with *todolist* - any generic todo list or a specific application? Please add a link if the second. *Programs also exist* could also do with some explanations/links if you really want to help the OP.